# Determine the direction of a GPS coordinate

Tags: android, gps, direction, magnetometer

I am trying determine the direction of a target location based on its GPS coords in relation to Magnetic North or True North. Based on where my phone is currently located, as determined by Android location services, how do I know which direction the target location is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method [Location.bearingTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo%28android.location.Location%29)

for example

```
bearing = currentLocation.bearingTo(targetLocation);
```